# ScrollView and .sheet

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview

I have a ScrollView with a ForEach loop, each rendering a View. In the View I have 3 renders of the below ActionItem (a button that displays a sheet). **The sheet does not show up with ScrollView but does with List**. I'd normally attach the .sheet at the ScrollView layer however, with each button rendering a different view it seems more appropriate to nest it.

How I could get this to work with ScrollView? I'm using Xcode 12

```
struct ActionItem<Content>: View where Content : View {
    public var text: String
    public var icon: String
    public var content: Content
    @State var isPresented = false
    
    init(text: String, icon: String, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.text = text
        self.icon = icon
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button (action: {
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
             withAnimation {
               self.isPresented = true
             }
            }
        }) {
            HStack(spacing: 2) {
                Image(systemName: icon).font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold))
                Text(text).fontWeight(.semibold)
                
            }.padding([.top, .bottom], Dimensions.spacing)
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], Dimensions.spacingMedium)
        }.foregroundColor(Color.gray).font(.subheadline).background(Color.grayWhiteTer)
        .cornerRadius(Dimensions.spacing)
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            self.content
        }
    }
}
```

In the View I'd render ActionItem such as Text, this also occurs if the View is ignored and the ActionItem is just directly in the ForEach. Same issue, sheet does not appear.

```
ActionItem(text: "", icon: "pencil") {
  Text("ok")
}
```

The list looks like this

```
import SwiftUI

struct ItemsList: View {
  @ObservedObject var itemModel: ItemModel
    
  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
      ScrollView {
        VStack {
            ForEach(itemModel.items, id: \.self) { item in
              ItemView(item: item)
            }
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
}}
```

Suggested callback update

```
struct ActionItem<Content>: View where Content : View {
    public var text: String
    public var icon: String
    public var content: () -> Content
    @State var isPresented = false
    
    init(text: String, icon: String, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.text = text
        self.icon = icon
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button (action: {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               withAnimation {
                self.isPresented = true
               }
            }
            
        }) {
            HStack(spacing: 2) {
                Image(systemName: icon).font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold))
                    Text(text).fontWeight(.semibold)
                
            }.padding([.top, .bottom], Dimensions.spacing)
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], Dimensions.spacingMedium)
        }.foregroundColor(Color.gray).font(.subheadline).background(Color.grayWhiteTer)
        .cornerRadius(Dimensions.spacing)
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            self.content()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving content as a callback (i.e. () -> Content) and call it in the sheet method instead of calling it in the initializer.. This will change when the view is created.

Comment: Thanks for getting back @BJB. It seems like that doesn't work. I added that in and put the code in the question above. I used 400 instead of .infinity as well because .infinity resulted in a new error `Thread 1: "CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]. Layer: <CALayer:0x60000...`

Comment: I'm sorry that was supposed to be max height and width.. try that now.

Comment: All good, just tried the maxWidth/maxHeight (that cleared the above comment error) as well as the async animation and seems like those don't work either. Updated my code above to reflect your suggestions

Comment: tried that as well, seems like that isn't working either, I put the code above at the bottom of the question

Comment: Ok, I've figured it out.. I had an extra .sheet hiding in a higher layer. Thanks very much for the help @BJB

Comment: great! glad you figured it out.. when in doubt always check up the hierarchy!